How to disable `ifdef FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL` in Chisel?
When generating code, I get garbage like
`ifdef ENABLE_INITIAL_REG_
    `ifdef FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
      `FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
    `endif // FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
    initial begin
      automatic logic [31:0] _RANDOM[0:0];
      `ifdef INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
        `INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
      `endif // INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
      `ifdef RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
        _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0] = `RANDOM;
        shifter_0 = _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0][1:0];
        shifter_1 = _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0][3:2];
        shifter_2 = _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0][5:4];
      `endif // RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
      if (reset) begin
        shifter_0 = 2'h0;
        shifter_1 = 2'h0;
        shifter_2 = 2'h0;
      end
    end // initial

Is there any way to disable these macros so that there is a cleaner code?
These are all the options that I use when generating
ChiselStage.emitSystemVerilog(
      gen = new top(0.U(2.W), 3),
      firtoolOpts = Array(
        "-disable-all-randomization",
        "-strip-debug-info",
        "-o",
        folderPath.toString + "/top.sv"
      )
    )


The correct option is -disable-all-randomization.  However, there's something wrong with the output. When I run this locally without and with the option, I'm able to remove the randomization code.
E.g., here is a program which produces similar output:
//> using scala "2.13.15"
//> using repository sonatype-s01:snapshots
//> using dep "org.chipsalliance::chisel::7.0.0-M2+208-892fa802-SNAPSHOT"
//> using plugin "org.chipsalliance:::chisel-plugin::7.0.0-M2+208-892fa802-SNAPSHOT"
//> using options "-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-language:reflectiveCalls", "-feature", "-Xcheckinit", "-Xfatal-warnings", "-Ywarn-dead-code", "-Ywarn-unused", "-Ymacro-annotations"

import chisel3._
import circt.stage.ChiselStage

class Foo extends Module {
  val a = IO(Input(UInt(2.W)))
  val b = IO(Output(UInt(2.W)))

  private val shifter = Reg(Vec(3, UInt(2.W)))

  (shifter.toSeq :+ b).foldLeft(a) { case (acc, x) => x :<= acc; x }
}

object Main extends App {

  private val commonOptions = Array(
    "-strip-debug-info",
    "-enable-layers=Verification,Verification.Assert,Verification.Assume,Verification.Cover"
  )

  println(
    ChiselStage.emitSystemVerilog(
      new Foo,
      firtoolOpts = commonOptions
    )
  )

  println(
    ChiselStage.emitSystemVerilog(
      new Foo,
      firtoolOpts = commonOptions :+ "-disable-all-randomization"
    )
  )
}

If I run this, using scala-cli with:
scala-cli 79232426.scala

I get the following two Verilog files printed out:
// Generated by CIRCT firtool-1.95.1

// Include register initializers in init blocks unless synthesis is set
`ifndef RANDOMIZE
  `ifdef RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
    `define RANDOMIZE
  `endif // RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
`endif // not def RANDOMIZE
`ifndef SYNTHESIS
  `ifndef ENABLE_INITIAL_REG_
    `define ENABLE_INITIAL_REG_
  `endif // not def ENABLE_INITIAL_REG_
`endif // not def SYNTHESIS

// Standard header to adapt well known macros for register randomization.

// RANDOM may be set to an expression that produces a 32-bit random unsigned value.
`ifndef RANDOM
  `define RANDOM $random
`endif // not def RANDOM

// Users can define INIT_RANDOM as general code that gets injected into the
// initializer block for modules with registers.
`ifndef INIT_RANDOM
  `define INIT_RANDOM
`endif // not def INIT_RANDOM

// If using random initialization, you can also define RANDOMIZE_DELAY to
// customize the delay used, otherwise 0.002 is used.
`ifndef RANDOMIZE_DELAY
  `define RANDOMIZE_DELAY 0.002
`endif // not def RANDOMIZE_DELAY

// Define INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_ for use in our modules below.
`ifndef INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
  `ifdef RANDOMIZE
    `ifdef VERILATOR
      `define INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_ `INIT_RANDOM
    `else  // VERILATOR
      `define INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_ `INIT_RANDOM #`RANDOMIZE_DELAY begin end
    `endif // VERILATOR
  `else  // RANDOMIZE
    `define INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
  `endif // RANDOMIZE
`endif // not def INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
module Foo(
  input        clock,
               reset,
  input  [1:0] a,
  output [1:0] b
);

  reg [1:0] shifter_0;
  reg [1:0] shifter_1;
  reg [1:0] shifter_2;
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    shifter_0 <= a;
    shifter_1 <= shifter_0;
    shifter_2 <= shifter_1;
  end // always @(posedge)
  `ifdef ENABLE_INITIAL_REG_
    `ifdef FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
      `FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
    `endif // FIRRTL_BEFORE_INITIAL
    initial begin
      automatic logic [31:0] _RANDOM[0:0];
      `ifdef INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
        `INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
      `endif // INIT_RANDOM_PROLOG_
      `ifdef RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
        _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0] = `RANDOM;
        shifter_0 = _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0][1:0];
        shifter_1 = _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0][3:2];
        shifter_2 = _RANDOM[/*Zero width*/ 1'b0][5:4];
      `endif // RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
    end // initial
    `ifdef FIRRTL_AFTER_INITIAL
      `FIRRTL_AFTER_INITIAL
    `endif // FIRRTL_AFTER_INITIAL
  `endif // ENABLE_INITIAL_REG_
  assign b = shifter_2;
endmodule

// Generated by CIRCT firtool-1.95.1
module Foo(
  input        clock,
               reset,
  input  [1:0] a,
  output [1:0] b
);

  reg [1:0] shifter_0;
  reg [1:0] shifter_1;
  reg [1:0] shifter_2;
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    shifter_0 <= a;
    shifter_1 <= shifter_0;
    shifter_2 <= shifter_1;
  end // always @(posedge)
  assign b = shifter_2;
endmodule

The former, without the option, has the randomization logic. The latter, with the option, has the randomization logic removed.
